# WHERE clause IN TRIGGER involving 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, where-clause

My trigger looks like this:

```
create trigger money after update on `things`
for each row
begin
SET @c1 = (SELECT sum(`thing_cost`) from `things`);
SET @c2 = (SELECT sum(`salary`) from `dude_base`);
UPDATE `current` SET `curr_cash` = @c1 * @c2 / 100
end;
$$
```

But I need to add something like this:

```
WHERE id2 from things = id2 from current AND WHERE id1 from dude_base = is1 from current
```

instead of "SELECT sum" thing, because I need to verify each row.

And I have hard time doing this without any syntax errors..

I am working on MySQL with newest phpmyadmin.

---

I also tried looking at something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET val=X WHERE someproperty = 1;
UPDATE table SET val=Y WHERE someproperty = 2;
```

But it still didin't work out.. at all.

Comment: This is kind of hard to understand. Can you post a sample of your data in these 3 tables, and what your output would look like after the trigger runs?

Comment: With regards to the exemplar goal SQL, could you simplify it as it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Ok, so in dudes table i got normal person id (PK), name, email etc.
In things table I got like id thing(PK), name etc. In current table I got boths id's from two tables (as FK), and curr cash. And I need to know what bought id from dudes, and what things from things table.

Comment: I think the suggestion was to actually post some *example data* in the question.  Show us the data, an example update, and the results you'd want...

Comment: OKey. So when I edit the value of item in my things table, there is automaticy update in current table. It sums all things and adds it to dude who "bought" something. And this is wrong, because I want to make that dude buys for him 1 thing, 2 thing, not sum of everything. And I want it to be listed like dude from id1 bought thins id2.

Comment: currently record is like: 523423424.53 (big numer of money), date, ID dude, ID thing

Comment: And I want output to look like: 
400, date, id of dude 3, id of thing 3
200, date, id of dude 3, id of thing 4
400, date, id of dude 2, id of thing 3
etc.

Comment: FYI: We don't do "bumps" here.  Please don't do that again.